# Регулярное выражение в django urls

Tags: python, django, url, django-urls

Есть такой urlpatterns в urls:

```
re_path('genre/(?P<genre>.*\s*)/delete/$', films.genre_delete, name='genre_delete')
```

и функция во views:

```
def genre_delete(requesr, genre=None):
    genre=genre
    try:
        genre_id = Genre.objects.get(id=genre)
        if genre_id:
            genre_id.delete()
```

при вводе в браузере `localhost:8000/genre/4/delete` во views переменная `genre` принимает значение `4/delete`.
Как исправить urls чтобы при переходе по ссылке `localhost:8000/genre/4/delete` переменной `genre` присваивался только id 4?

Comment: `genre/(?P<genre>\d+)/delete$` ?

Comment: Спасибо, получилось